# XML ERROR in Table while opening Excel from Desktop

Tags: excel, xslt

I am in EBS application and Getting below error while open the Excel from Desktop(copied the Excel file to Desktop).

1. XML ERROR in Table
2. REASON: Bad Value
3. FILE:   C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\XXC_210219.xml-1.xls
4. GROUP:  Row
5. TAG:    Cell
6. ATTRIB: Index
7. VALUE:  12

I am adding new column Debit2 to the existing query (PLSQL Procedure).
    BEGIN

```
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,crlf);


    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<?xml version="1.0"?>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,' xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,' xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,' xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,' xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,' <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </DocumentProperties>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </ExcelWorkbook>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Styles>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Style ss:ID="s22">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Font ss:Size="8"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00_);[Red]\(#,##0.00\)"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </Style>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Style ss:ID="s24">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Font ss:Size="8"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0;[Red]\(#,##0\)"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </Style>'||crlf);

    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Style ss:ID="s25">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Font ss:Size="8"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </Style>'||crlf);

    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Style ss:ID="s26">'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Font ss:Size="8"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </Style>'||crlf);

    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Style ss:ID="date">'||crlf);
        FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  <Font ss:Size="8"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<NumberFormat ss:Format="[ENG][$-409]d\-mmm\-yy;@"/>'||crlf);
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'</Style>'||crlf);


    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'  </Styles>'||crlf);

    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Worksheet ss:Name="Payables Entries">'||crlf);

    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Table>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="35"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="57"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="45"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="49"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="120"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="58"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="111"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="57"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="58"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="52"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="230"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="52"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="41"/>');
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="52"/>');

      FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,
              '<Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Period</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Effective Date</Data></Cell>'||
              '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Journal Line No</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Debit</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Credit</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">GL Account</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Check Amount</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Debit2</Data></Cell>'||   --> adding this column
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Bank Account</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Check Number</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Check Date</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Vendor Name</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Cleared Date</Data></Cell>'||
                        '<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Void Date</Data></Cell></Row>');


      for c in (
        Select '<Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">'||period_name||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="date"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||TO_CHAR(EFFECTIVE_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||JE_LINE_NUM||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||entered_dr||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||entered_cr||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">'||acct||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||amount||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||entered_dr||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">'||bank_account_name||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||check_number||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="date"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||to_char(check_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'</Data></Cell>'||
           '<Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">'||xmlreplace(vendor_name)||'</Data></Cell>'||
           decode(cleared_date,null,null,'<Cell ss:StyleID="date"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||to_char(cleared_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'</Data></Cell>')||
              decode(void_date,null,'</Row>','<Cell ss:StyleID="date" ss:Index="12"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||to_char(void_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'</Data></Cell></Row>') line
          from (SELECT y.je_category,
        y.je_source,
        y.period_name,
        y.name,
        y.description,
        A.USER_NAME,
        x.effective_date,
        x.entered_dr,
        x.entered_cr,
        x.description line_desc,
        x.je_header_id,
        x.je_line_num,
        x.attribute1,
        z.segment1
        ||'-'
        ||z.segment2
        ||'-'
        ||z.segment3
        ||'-'
        ||z.segment4
        ||'-'
        ||z.segment5
        ||'-'
        ||Z.SEGMENT6 ACCT,
         XLT.SOURCE_ID_INT_1
      FROM apps.gl_je_lines x,
        apps.gl_je_headers y,
        APPS.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS Z,
        APPS.FND_USER A,
        APPS.GL_IMPORT_REFERENCES GLI,
        XLA.XLA_TRANSACTION_ENTITIES xlt
      WHERE x.code_combination_id=z.code_combination_id
      AND y.je_header_id         =x.je_header_id
      AND segment5               ='102005'
      AND x.effective_date BETWEEN gldate_from and gldate_to
      AND Y.CREATED_BY    =A.USER_ID
      AND JE_SOURCE       ='Payables'
      AND X.JE_HEADER_ID  =GLI.JE_HEADER_ID
      AND X.JE_LINE_NUM   =GLI.JE_LINE_NUM
      AND GLI.REFERENCE_5 =XLT.ENTITY_ID
      ),
      APPS.ap_checks_all aca
    WHERE SOURCE_ID_INT_1=CHECK_ID
    and aca.check_number in('261785','3483233')
    ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE, ACA.CHECK_NUMBER,je_line_num
      ) loop


        FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,c.line);
      End Loop;

        FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'</Table>'||crlf);
```

END;

Here is the data file...can you please help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  </DocumentProperties>
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
  </ExcelWorkbook>
  <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="s22">
  <Font ss:Size="8"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00_);[Red]\(#,##0.00\)"/>
  </Style>

  <Style ss:ID="s24">
  <Font ss:Size="8"/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0;[Red]\(#,##0\)"/>
  </Style>

  <Style ss:ID="s25">
  <Font ss:Size="8"/>
  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
  </Style>

  <Style ss:ID="s26">
  <Font ss:Size="8"/>
  <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
  </Style>

<Style ss:ID="date">
  <Font ss:Size="8"/>
<NumberFormat ss:Format="[ENG][$-409]d\-mmm\-yy;@"/>

</Style>

  </Styles>

<Worksheet ss:Name="Payables Entries">

<Table>
    <Column ss:Width="35"/>
    <Column ss:Width="57"/>
    <Column ss:Width="45"/>
    <Column ss:Width="49"/>
    <Column ss:Width="120"/>
    <Column ss:Width="58"/>
    <Column ss:Width="111"/>
    <Column ss:Width="57"/>
    <Column ss:Width="58"/>
    <Column ss:Width="52"/>
    <Column ss:Width="230"/>
    <Column ss:Width="52"/>
    <Column ss:Width="41"/>
    <Column ss:Width="52"/>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Period</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Effective Date</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Journal Line No</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Debit</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Credit</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">GL Account</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check Amount</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Debit2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Bank Account</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check Number</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check Date</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Vendor Name</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Cleared Date</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Void Date</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">JAN-19</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-04</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">6</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">7678.34</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">001-00-001-000-102005-0013</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">7678.34</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Dist-Wachovia</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s24">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">261785</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-04</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">LAURELWOOD EQUITIES, LLC</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-08</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">JAN-19</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-04</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">5</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">21242.38</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">001-00-001-000-102005-0013</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">4185</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">21242.38</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Dist-Wachovia</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s24">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">3483233</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2017-10-10</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Morgan Lewis &amp; Bockius, LLP_CO-4129739</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date" ss:Index="12">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-04</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</Table>

  <WorksheetOptions

  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

  <PageSetup>

  <Footer x:Data=";CPage ;P of ;N"/>

  </PageSetup>

<Print>

<ValidPrinterInfo/>

</Print>

<Selected/>

<Panes>

<Pane>

<Number>3</Number>

<ActiveRow>5</ActiveRow>

</Pane>

</Panes>

<ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>

<ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>

</WorksheetOptions>

</Worksheet>

 </Workbook>
```

Comment: I believe the `ss:Index` number is 1-based, not 0-based, so you are trying to set `ss:index` to 12 for a cell that is actually in index 13. But you should probably set it to 14, if you want it to appear in the Void Date column. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC how did you know Index is having 13 ? It was working fine before...and not working after adding Debit2 column...any reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @TimC

I changed Index 12 to 14 and It was working (tested with adding Debit2) and it was not working if i add Date on Bank ,Cebit2 columns

```
 XML ERROR in Table
 REASON:    Bad Value
 FILE:  C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\XXC_210219.xml-4.xls 
 GROUP: Row
 TAG:   Cell
 ATTRIB:    Index
 VALUE: 14
```

Adding 2 columns...

```
  FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="49"/>');---
  FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="49"/>');
  FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'<Column ss:Width="49"/>');


'<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Date on Bank</Data></Cell>'||
'<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Debit2</Data></Cell>'||
'<Cell ss:StyleID="s26"><Data ss:Type="String">Cebit2</Data></Cell>'||

  select  '<Cell ss:StyleID="s25"><Data ss:Type="String">'||to_char(null)||'</Data </Cell>'||,  -- date on bank
   '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||case when entered_dr>0 then amount else 0 end||'</Data></Cell>'||, --debit2
   '<Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">'||case when entered_cr>0 then amount else 0 end||'</Data></Cell>'||, --Credit2
     decode(cleared_date,null,null,'<Cell ss:StyleID="date"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||to_char(cleared_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'</Data></Cell>')||
      decode(void_date,null,'</Row>','<Cell ss:StyleID="date" ss:Index="14"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">'||to_char(void_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')||'</Data></Cell></Row>') line
  from table
--------------
--- Data file
--------------
    <Table>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Period</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Effective Date</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Journal Line No</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Debit</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Credit</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">GL Account</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check Amount</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Date On Bank</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Debit2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Cebit2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Bank Account</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check Number</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check Date</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Vendor Name</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Cleared Date</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s26">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Void Date</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">JAN-19</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-17</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">5</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">25963.2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">001-00-001-000-102005-0013</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">16786.2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">16786.2</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Brown Check Dist-Wachovia</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Wire</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s24">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">30002016</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-17</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">AFFAKI_CO-4497526</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">JAN-19</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-18</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">15</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">175</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">001-00-001-000-102005-0013</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">175</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">175</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Dist-Wachovia</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s24">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">3245065</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2012-05-08</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Richard P. McCann_IN-2271671</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date" ss:Index="14">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-18</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">JAN-19</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-18</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">12</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">1235.4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">001-00-001-000-102005-0013</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">1235.4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String"/>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">1235.4</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s22">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Dist-Wachovia</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">Check</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s24">
            <Data ss:Type="Number">3255870</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2012-08-14</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
            <Data ss:Type="String">C. James Georgeson_IN-469416</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="date" ss:Index="14">
            <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2019-01-18</Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
    </Table>
```

Comment: @Tim C, Can you please help me on the above...tanks in advanced.